# ps3 controller failed to pair

Tags: ps3, joystick

I'm trying to pair my ps3 controller with trusty. I've tried this so far:

> $ sudo sixpair
>   Current Bluetooth master: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
>   Setting master bd_addr to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

And then I unplug my controller and run this command:

> $ sixad --start
>   D-Bus setup failed: Name already in use
>   sixad-bin[4843]: started
>   sixad-bin[4843]: sixad started, press the PS button now

But when I press the PS button, **nothing happens!**

I've searched a lot in Google and this process works everywhere, but I don't know it doesn't work here...thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Sixaxis or DualShock3? For me the Sixaxis works flawlessly, but I have issues with the DS3 and it seemingly randomly works, and I usually have to reboot every time it fails or disconnects.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if this is a really obvious answer, but: Check the battery isn't flat on your controller.

I had this exact same problem. Of course the `sixpair` command worked because the controller had power from the USB cable, but once unplugged - nothing...